# There is a list from which i need to find duplicates

Tags: python, list

I have written a code, which is able to do so. However, i am not able to find the exact value. The code i have written is sharing all values with me, instead of just 1 duplicate value

```
some_list=['a','b','c','b','d','m','n','n']
a=[]
for items in some_list:
  if some_list.count(items) > 1:
      a.append(items)
print (a)
```

Comment: Try `for items in set(some_list)`?

Comment: Or ```a=set()``` and ```a.add(items)```?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is appending all duplicates value to new list i.e. 'a'. To keep only 1 duplicate value, you need to check whether the same value is already there in your list or not. If this is not there, then only you should append that value to your list. I have modified your code, to suite this need .

```
enter code here
some_list=['a','b','c','b','d','m','n','n']
a=[]
for items in some_list:
  if some_list.count(items) > 1 and a.count(items) == 0:
      a.append(items)
print (a)
```

Output:

```
['b', 'n']
```

Comment: what is the relevance of adding "a.count(items) == 0:" in the code?

Comment: "a.count(items)==0" checks that the same item is not already appended in the list 'a'. For ex: on reaching first 'b', you will find a.count('b')=0, and append 'b' to the list. Next time when you find 'b', a.count('b') is equal to 1, so we will not append second 'b' to the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
some_list=['a','b','c','b','d','m','n','n']
a=[]
for items in some_list:
    if some_list.count(items) > 1:
        if items not in a:
            a.append(items)
print (a)
```

output:

```
['b', 'n']
```

or:

```
some_list=['a','b','c','b','d','m','n','n']
a=[]
for items in some_list:
    if some_list.count(items) > 1:

        a.append(items)
a=set(a)
print (a)
```

out:

```
['b', 'n']
```

Comment: Why do you add the code line "if items not in a:"?   What is the relevance of this codeline

Comment: If a character is added to the list, don't add it a second time. There are other solutions. If you want to put them

Comment: Hi Benyamin, could you be helpful to elaborate it a little bit more

Answer (score 0):

We can utilize `Counter` module from `Collections` package.

```
from collections import Counter
final_list = []
cntr = Counter(['a','b','c','b','d','m','n','n'])
for i in cntr.iteritems():
    if i[1] > 1:
        final_list.append(i[0])
print final_list
```

For more info on `Counter` module please go through https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Answer (score 0):

`Counter` and `defaultdict` data structures from `collections` module perfectly suits the use-case, here is another approach using normal `dict` data structure which may be more intuitive for beginners in understanding the approach.

**Approach**:

Step-1: Building a dictionary with item as key and its occurrences as value.

Step-2 Filter out items whose occurrences is less than 2, in other words, select items whose occurrences are greater than 1.

```
def get_duplicates(some_list): 
    frequency_counter = {}

    # Step-1
    for item in some_list:
        if item in frequency_counter:
            frequency_counter[item] += 1
        else:
            frequency_counter[item] = 1

    # Step-2
    return [item for item, count in frequency_counter.items() if count > 1]

In [2]: get_duplicates(['a','b','c','b','d','m','n','n'])                                                                                     
Out[2]: ['b', 'n']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use list comprehension with `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

[e for e, freq in Counter(some_list).items() if freq > 1]
```

**output:**

```
['b', 'n']
```

---

another approach will be to sort your list:

```
previous = None
elemetns = set()
for i in sorted(some_list):
    if previous == i:
        elemetns.update(i)
    previous = i

print(elements)
```

**output:**

```
{'b', 'n'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work,If you'd add one more condition in your **if** Statement.

```
some_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'm', 'n', 'n']
a = []
for items in some_list:
    if some_list.count(items) > 1 and items not in a:
        a.append(items)
print (a)
```

Output:-

```
['b', 'n']
```